# Сортировка массивов int чисел

Tags: java, алгоритм

Имеется 2 массива с числами. Элементы в них находятся в некой зависимости, т.е. 0 элемент 1 массива "связан" с 0 элементом 2 массива и т.д. Необходимо как-то отсортировать объекты по убыванию в отношении Vi/Wi и записать это в новое множество или массив. И далее при необходимости когда объекты оттуда будут браться, как-то получать их изначальные отношения.

```
static int[] values = new int[] {10, 8, 3, 8, 8}; // цены
static int[] weights = new int[] {8, 3, 4, 3, 3}; //вес предметов
```

PS: решаю задачу о рюкзаке методом жадных алгоритмов

Comment: кажется, удобнее сделать отдельный класс с полями value и weight и написать компаратор для него/реализовать Comparaple, а создать массив из объектов этого класса

Comment: Класс отдельный это не проблема, проблема в том как это реализовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<Entity> entities = Arrays.asList(new Entity(3,5),new Entity(5,7),new Entity(3,1),new Entity(1,10));
        Collections.sort(entities);
        entities.forEach(System.out::println);
     }
}

class Entity implements Comparable<Entity> {

        private int weight;
        private int cost;

        public Entity(int weight, int cost) {
            this.weight = weight;
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        private double getMeasure(){
            return cost * 1.0 / weight;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Entity entity) {
            double thisMeasure = getMeasure();
            double thatMeasure = entity.getMeasure();

            if(thisMeasure < thatMeasure) return -1;
            return thisMeasure > thatMeasure ? 1 : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
        return "Entity{" +
                "weight=" + weight +
                ", cost=" + cost +
                ", difference=" + getMeasure() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Восхитительно! Страница кода без единого  слова, как это все относится к вопросу.

Comment: @Эникейщик при этом он полностью отвечает на вопрос "как сделать», его можно просто скопировать/вставить и посмотреть (убедиться в) результат(е), в нем достаточно легко разобраться при минимальном знании языка и в нем нет вообще ничего лишнего (к примеру в классе напрашиваются гетеры, но они не являются необходимыми, поэтому опущены)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так:

```
List<Integer> sortedValues = Stream
            .generate(new Supplier<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
                private int index = -1;

                @Override
                public Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> get() {
                    index++;
                    return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(values[index], weights[index]);
                }})
            .limit(values.length)
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(toList());
```